# Shortcuts no visual code - ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Hoje instalei o visual code no linux, já o utilizava anteriormente mas no windows, acontece que algunsdos atalhos não estão funcionando e isso está prejudicando bastante minha produtividade.
Um desses atalhos [ ctrl + ' ]  que de acordo com o manual seria utilizado para abrir o terminal, porem não faz isso. Muitos outros atalhos não funcionam também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vários atalhos são diferentes mesmo no Linux. Aqui vc pode conferir a lista oficial completa.

No Linux seria <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + `</kbd>   *create new terminal*

https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Mas logicamente vc pode fazer o *override* desses atalhos por aqui e colocar o comando que desejar...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tentei utilizar os atalhos dessa tabela mas por algum motivo não funcionam, mas obrigado :)

Comment: @RafaelChaves confere como está a config do seu teclado no sistema operacional, se está pt-br ABNTII ou em inglês.... testa se os acentos estão corretos mesmo. Em último caso coloca um atalho qualquer que não use acentos ou caracteres especiais para testar

Comment: Verifiquei agora, os atalhos vieram desconfigurados

Comment: @RafaelChaves de boa, olha se não é alguma config de teclado, e se precisar essa é a lista dos atalhos n Windows https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Estou na mesma dificuldade por aqui, os atalhos apresentados não correspondem as ações descritas, ou então simplesmente não funcionam. Também venho do Windows e agora estou usando o Ubuntu 20.04.

Exclusivamente para o seu caso (que também era o meu problema) eu descobri um paliativo que é o ctrl+j, que não abre exatamente o terminal, mas o último painel inferior que você abriu (em geral costuma ser o terminal).

Comment: Quem negativa uma resposta dessas?